# How to get all Buttons ID's in one time on Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

I have 16 `Button`s in my `Activity`   and I have to initialize those inside onCreate(). 
Is there any way to initialize all buttons in one single line code?(loops etc.)
Code should take all buttons `R.id.`  from `XML` Layout and process....

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's say you named your button `button_0, button_1, .. button_15`. You can do:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
    int id = getResources().getIdentifier("button_"+i, "id", getPackageName());
    button[i] = (Button) findViewById(id);
}
```

Comment: the identifier should be descriptive, then the codes are not well understood.

Answer (score 7):

Well, if all 16 of those buttons are inside one view or layout, then you could do the following.

```
ArrayList<View> allButtons; 
allButtons = ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.button_container)).getTouchables();
```

This assumes that your container (in this example a `LinearLayout`) contains no `Touchable` that is not a `Button`.

Answer (score 2):

1. use [Butterknife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) view injections library
2. Download [Android ButterKnife Zelezny](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7369?pr=phpStorm) plugin for `Android Studio` or `Intellij IDEA`
   and **initialize all your views** from current layout **by 1 click**

Answer (score 1):

For xamarin android :

```
List<Button>() allButtons = new List<Button>();
for (int i = 1; i < 15; i++)
{
    int id = this.Resources.GetIdentifier("btn" + i.ToString(), "id", this.PackageName);
    Button btn = (Button)FindViewById(id);
    allButtons.Add(btn);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

This method takes all buttons inside the layout, hope it helps. Easy to implement & you can use it for almost every project, no libraries required.

```
public List<Button> getAllButtons(ViewGroup layout){
        List<Button> btn = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i =0; i< layout.getChildCount(); i++){
            View v =layout.getChildAt(i);
            if(v instanceof Button){
                btn.add((Button) v);
            }
        }
        return btn;
    }
```

**Example**

```
List<Button> btn_list = getAllButtons(myRelativeLayout);
Button my_btn = btn_list.get(0);
my_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
     @Override
     public void onClick(View view) {
                Log.d("btn_test", "onClick: hello");
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kotlin, and your buttons have ids in the form of *button1, button2... button16*, you can do something like this:

```
var btn = ArrayList<Button>(16)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_game_screen)

    for(i in 0 until 16) {
        var id = resources.getIdentifier("button"+(i+1), "id", packageName)
        btn.add(findViewById<View>(id) as Button)
        btn[i].setText("something") //or do whatever now 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only know the container id or the button ids are all different try this:

Activity(on create method before setContentView)

```
List<Integer> idButtons= new ArrayList<>();
//container_button is my button container
RelativeLayout containerButton = findViewById(R.id.container_button);
for(int i =0; i < containerButton.getChildCount(); i++){
    View v = containerButton.getChildAt(i);
    if(v instanceof Button){
        idButtons.add(((Button) v).getId());
    }
 }
```

Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp">

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonac"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/red_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="AC"
    android:onClick="pulsacion" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttondel"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/buttonac"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonac"
    android:background="@drawable/red_button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:text="DEL"
    android:onClick="pulsacion" />

    [...]
</RelativeLayout>
```