# How to get all buttons at once?

Tags: android, android-layout

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.button1);
```

That's the only way I know to get the button, but I have 45 buttons and it's too hard for me to get the buttons one by one.

Is there is any way to get all the buttons at once?

Comment: use DataBinding concept

Answer (score 1):

If you have 45 buttons on the screen, I'm thinking maybe you need to use a RecyclerView, to display one button, and then duplicate it a lot of times.
Their click listener will depend on the button index.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understood your question i think you can find your answer on this post.
[How to get all Buttons ID's in one time on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639218/how-to-get-all-buttons-ids-in-one-time-on-android)

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like

```
val root = findViewById<ViewGroup>(android.R.id.content)

val buttons =  (0 until root.childCount)
                    .mapNotNull { root.getChildAt(it) as? Button }
                    .toList()
```

in `onCreate` of your activity