# How to get all ImageButton ID's on Android with Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `ImageButton`s
and i send a Toast from `override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)`
when its clicked successful.

I want loop trough all `ImageButton`s to add the `setOnClickListener` to them.

this works:

## works without a loop:

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.r1col1).setOnClickListener {
            toastContentDescription(it)
        }
    }
    private fun toastContentDescription(it: View) {
        val contentDescription = it.contentDescription
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, contentDescription, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        myToast.show()
    }
}
```

## works not, not start anymore

I found a example for Android Java Buttons here: [How to get all Buttons ID's in one time on Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22639218/how-to-get-all-buttons-ids-in-one-time-on-android)

So i modified my code to following. But then the app not start anymore (gives me no errors).

i guess i have to get the id first and then the problem is solved.

```kotlin
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        for (i in 0..4) {
            val id: Int = resources.getIdentifier("R.id.r1col$i", "id", this.packageName)
            findViewById<ImageButton>(id).setOnClickListener {
                toastContentDescription(it)
            }
        }
    }
    private fun toastContentDescription(it: View) {
        val contentDescription = it.contentDescription
        val myToast = Toast.makeText(applicationContext, contentDescription, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
        myToast.show()
    }
}
```

Is there any way to set the setOnClickListener to all ImageButtons in a loop (etc.) Code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `"R.id."` prefix from the string you’re passing.